# Post is automatically trimmed

Tags: bug, edits

When I tried to post an answer with the following content:

```
ha = a.group_by(&:itself).map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}.to_h
hb = b.group_by(&:itself).map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}.to_h
ha.merge(hb){|_, va, vb| (va - vb).abs}.inject([]){|a, (k, v)| a << [k] * v}.flatten
```

the post was automatically changed to:

group_by(&:itself).map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}.to_h
hb = b.group_by(&:itself).map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}.to_h
ha.merge(hb){|_, va, vb| (va - vb).abs}.inject([]){|a, (k, v)| a << [k] * v}.flatten

That is, the code formatting with four spaces before each line was removed, and the initial `ha = a.` was also trimmed.

Comment: Did you add a line before the code?

Comment: @Braiam No. If I added a line before with a few periods, then the problem disappeared.

Comment: Was it a code-only post?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, it was.

Comment: Thank goodness the first variable wasn't called `gimmehtehcodezpls` ;)

Comment: Any progress on the bug/feature fix?

Answer (score 17):

This is caused by the automatic greetings removal, even though the [regular expression](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/151385) shouldn't actually hit this case.

It removed any "ha" at the beginning of a post, and continues to remove stuff on the line until it hits "punctuation", in this case the period before `group_by`.

Changing the variable name to anything that doesn't fit the greetings regexp does fix the issue.

The greetings removal probably shouldn't be run on parts formatted as code.

Comment: That seems to be the case.

Answer (score 5):

group_by(&:itself).map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}.to_h
    hb = b.group_by(&:itself).map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}.to_h
    ha.merge(hb){|_, va, vb| (va - vb).abs}.inject([]){|a, (k, v)| a << [k] * v}.flatten

^ Result of copy & pasting the code and formatting with Ctrl-K. Preview looked correct

Comment: Nope, it doesn't...

Comment: @Braiam You're right. However, the preview window looked fine to me.

Answer (score 5):

Let's see...

```
ha = a.group_by(&:itself).map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}.to_h
hb = b.group_by(&:itself).map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}.to_h
ha.merge(hb){|_, va, vb| (va - vb).abs}.inject([]){|a, (k, v)| a << [k] * v}.flatten
```

if it works.

---

I'm presuming it trims all the spaces in the first line of the post, which I believe is actually good (if the preview warned you about it).